# why should we use parent in a Comment model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

what are self and parent?
this is part of a comment app

> models.py

```
  class Comment(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
        email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
        parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because a comment can be another comment's child, `self` stands for `class Comment` here.
for example:

```
father=Comment(user=...)
father.save()
son=Comment(user=...)
son.parent=father
son.save()
```

Comment: how does it work in an application like Instagram? I think this isn't still clear for me

Comment: Great example is Reddit. Since comments have hierarchy